# Create jar command doesn't find file

Tags: java, windows

```
build> jar cvfe test\MyJavaLibrary.jar Main -C test\java Main.class foo\SomeClass.class
foo\SomeClass.class : no such file or directory
added manifest
adding: Main.class(in = 444) (out= 308)(deflated 30%)
```

The corresponding directory structure is

```
build/
  test/
    java/
      foo/
        SomeClass.class
      Main.class
```

It is very strange that it works correctly when using `test\java\foo\SomeClass.class` as the last argument instead. Fine, but that doesn't work when I do the same for the first argument, that is `test\java\Main.class`. The behaviour appears to be very inconsistent.

**Why can it not find `foo\SomeClass.class`, or better, what is the right way to create the Jar?**

> java version "1.8.0_102"

Answer (score 1):

The executable that you're running from the command-line appears to start in the `build` directory, and as such, it doesn't know where the `foo\SomeClass.class` file is relative to `build` - this would also explain why `test\java\foo\SomeClass.class` works (it knows how to find the file relative to the execution directory).

If you were to have the `foo` folder on the top level inside `build`, I believe it would work correctly, but because `foo` is nested within two layers of directories, the executable has no idea where to look for a folder with that name in its current directory.

Comment: But that's what the `-C test\java` flag is for, no? Otherwise, how would it find `Main.class`?

Comment: Perhaps only the first path is affected by the "-C test\java" option?

Comment: You're right, the argument only effects the following inputfile. See the answer I added.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer in a documentation page I haven't seen before.

> -C  dir
>   Temporarily changes directories to dir while processing the following inputfiles argument. Multiple -C dir inputfiles sets are allowed.

So apparently the `-C` argument would need to be placed for every input, not just specified once.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html